# thunderbird логирование файлового обмена на почте

Tags: c#, linux, astra-linux, thunderbird

Я хочу написать программу для логирования входящих и исходящих сообщений с компьютера. OS стоит Astra Linux 1.5. Полноценного решения этого вопроса я не нашел. Есть мысль - следить за папкой, в которую сгружаются сообщения, когда приходят, и писать в файлик информацию об этом, но это закроет только один протокол. Проблема в том, что есть IMAP и POP3. На каком будет работать клиент - не известно. В какую сторону стоит попробовать копать, чтобы решить этот вопрос?

Я читал о том, что в thunderbird используется механизм web-расширений. Может стоит дописать какой-нибудь скрипт (хоть я в js и не силен...)

В дальнейшем, есть мысль выгрузки всех логов на другой компьютер, в котором программа будет это всё обобщать и структурировать, а затем загружать в бд.